# ImportError: No module when running uwsgi

Tags: python, uwsgi

I can run the server in flask development mode correctly.

I think I missing some params to run the **uwsgi** server so that got the error message.

## run **uwsgi** command

```
uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:4245 --module web --callable app --processes 4 --threads 2
```

## Error log

```
*** Operational MODE: preforking+threaded ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./web.py", line 19, in <module>
    from model.release_schedule import ReleaseSchedule
ImportError: No module named model.release_schedule
```

## web.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
from flask import request, url_for
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_request_params import bind_request_params
from flask import g
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import pymongo
import json
from webargs import Arg
from webargs.flaskparser import use_args, use_kwargs
import yaml
import time, functools
from pdb import set_trace
from pandas_helper import PandasHelper
import errors
from app_helper import *
from model.release_schedule import ReleaseSchedule
from model.history import History
from model.report_type_symbol import ReportTypeSymbol
from model.weekly_history import WeeklyHistory
from mongo import Mongo

# load config file
APP_CFG = yaml.load(open("app.yml", "r"))
MSG = yaml.load(open("message.yaml", "r"))
```

[image]

Comment: You should have an `__init__.py` in the model package.

Comment: @garnertb cool you solved the problem, but why can I ran it perfectly in flask debug mode  without __init__.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an `__init__.py` in the model folder if you want to use it as a python package.  It was probably working for in debug mode because the parent directory was in your `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: What makes it that the OP is using it as a python package with this uwsgi command? How do you see that it expects it to be a package?